# Running the Event-drops demo

Tags: node.js, d3.js, event-drops

I am trying to get a d3.js library called [Event-Drops](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops) working under a windows machine. Specifically, I want to run the [demo](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/tree/master/demo) and learn how it all works by tweaking one thing at a time.

Now, the github readme for event-drop has instructions to how to do so but I am unable to get anywhere with them. It recommends you install the relevant dependencies first. I am fairly new to the world of JavaScript and according to what I understand the dependencies would require installation of nodejs and a npm install of d3? Local or global install?

Secondly, the install instructions require you to run

```
make install
make run
```

which if understand correctly are fairly difficult to install under windows? I also have XAMPP installed which I assume I need to run the demo on a local server?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Node to play with EventDrops, unless you want to contribute (which would be great... yes, I'm a core maintainer. :p)

You can test it without Node either with the [related JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rqxusw5/9/) or by including it directly in your page such as:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/event-drops/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/event-drops"></script>
```

You should then be able to test it using [demo code](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/blob/master/demo/demo.js) as inspiration for instance.

Comment: I was only able to get this demo to work with any 4.x / 5.x release of D3 (currently `d3@5.9` and `event-drops@1.2.0`. Newer releases of `event-drops` do not appear to work with the demo.